# Understanding View to add user to Django Group

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to wrap my head around views/viewsets atm, specifically with adding a user to a DRF group.

I understand so far that views can be named arbitrarily and can just be thrown into a views.py file - sometimes in a ViewSet if they're related. My main question is do they get called automatically? I'm coming from a JS background so I'm used to a method being defined and then explicitly being called.

Here's my code for a ViewSet with generic code for adding a user:

```
class ActorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Actors
    queryset = Actors.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ActorSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = ['firstname','ethnicity','user','id']

    def add_to_group(self):
        desired_group_name = request.GET.get("group_name")
        my_group = Group.objects.get(name=desired_group_name)
        my_group.user_set.add(your_user)
```

Does add_to_group get called whenever a new Actor is created if the code specifies something about a post request?

Thanks for clearing things up! :)

Comment: As far as I know, you have to implement a method `post` in the class. The post method will be located and executed by Django itself when it gets request POST for this view. You must link it in `urls.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just decided to write the code.

```py
class ActorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Actors
    queryset = Actors.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ActorSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = ['firstname','ethnicity','user','id']

    def post(self, request):  # it was named "add_to_group"
        desired_group_name = request.GET.get("group_name")
        my_group = Group.objects.get(name=desired_group_name)
        my_group.user_set.add(your_user)
        
        return HttpResponse()  # Note, it must return something for browser
```

Here is some useful documentation - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-singleobjectmixin-with-view